# DateTime binding default error message using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, binding

i'm using Linq to SQL for my model with a **custom** validation layer. I cannot find the way to edit or change the default message:

> The value '29/34/1980' is not valid for BirthDate.

BirthDate is of course my textbox. Any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT**: this is the simple code i'm using:

```
<%= Html.Label("Data di Nascita (GG/MM/AAAA)", "BirthDate")%>
<%= Html.TextBox("BirthDate", Model.BirthDate) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("BirthDate", " *") %>
```

and this is the validation code, that does not override the default message:

```
if (!(person.BirthDate > DateTime.MinValue)) // Diverso dal default
    _validation.AddError("BirthDate", "Il campo 'Data di nascita' non è valido");
```

Comment: What's the custom validation layer?

Comment: Custom validation layer = not using validation attributes, but another classe the will validate a person object and return a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a DateTimePicker for your TextBox? Try specifying a format like "yyyy-MM-dd" for it and Parse the string to a DateTime first.

Comment: no date picker, just the textbox of a strongly typed View with the model property "BirthDate" as value. No chance to parse or try parse... mvc framework is taking it first...